# Por que o endereço de alguns sites contém número após o www?

Tags: url, link

Por que existem urls que contém algum número após o www? (www1, www3, www12)

O que isso influencia?

É possível eu criar um link assim?

**Ex:**

http://www1.folha.uol.com.br

http://www3.veduca.com.br/

http://www12.senado.gov.br/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sim, é possível!

Isso geralmente é feito por um processo chamado de `balanceamento de carga`. O balanceamento de carga é, basicamente, dividr a carga (ou seja, solicitações de sites que, por sua vez requerem algum poder de processamento e memória em um servidor web) ao longo de vários servidores web, em vez de ter `um único servidor para fazer todo o trabalho`. Ele geralmente consiste de uma `unidade central` que monitora a carga dos outros servidores, e `distribui as requisições` enviadas a um servidor que tem a `menor carga` no momento. www3 é um daqueles servidores que recebem requisições Web do `controlador central`.

Para um site normal, isso é desnecessário a menos que recebe milhares de requisições por segundo (por exemplo, Google), mas para aplicações web complexas este processo mantém a aplicação web com um bom desempenho, bem como o aumento da disponibilidade (se um desses servidores falhar, o resto ainda será capaz de lidar com as requisições).

Se você quiser aprender mais sobre o balanceamento de carga, você pode começar [aqui](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zHn2G71hoIk).

Esses `números referem-se` aos nomes dos servidores no pool de balanceamento de carga, já que cada servidor precisa ter um nome único. Eles poderiam também ter tomado uma convenção de nomenclatura diferente, como nomear cada servidor com o nome de um planeta. Nesse caso, você veria uma URL como `namekuseijin.goku.com.br` ou `planetavegeta.goku.com.br`

```
Mas se WWW.GOOGLE.COM não tiver um www3? Então como será feito o balanceamento de carga?
```

Existem vários mecanismos que podem ser usados para fazer balanceamento de carga; a maioria dos maiores sites usam uma mistura deles.

`Primeiro`, a maioria deles usa um [CDN](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u0NtUPpebCo) (`rede de distribuição de conteúdo`) que hospeda seu conteúdo em servidores espalhados geograficamente, de modo que as requisições de clientes podem ser atendidos pelos servidores nas proximidades. Na maioria dos casos CDNs são praticamente uma necessidade em site que tem uma grande quantidade de mídia como Tumblr, Flickr, Imgur, Youtube, etc. Eles não são tão necessários para sites que possuem apenas conteudo em texto, por exemplo.

`Segundo`, se você fizer uma pesquisa de DNS em www.google.com (por exemplo, `host www.google.com` usando o Linux), você verá que ele dá várias respostas para o mesmo endereço de host:

```
www.google.com has address 74.125.226.81
www.google.com has address 74.125.226.80
www.google.com has address 74.125.226.83
www.google.com has address 74.125.226.84
www.google.com has address 74.125.226.82
```

Isto significa que `qualquer objeto`(imagens, vídeos, etc.) de www.google.com pode ser provido por um desses endereços; se todo mundo recebe um objeto aleatoriamente de um desses endereços, `então, a carga ficará balanceada entre os endereços`.

Comment: +1 muita boa sua resposta, entretanto sugiro você dar uma conferida nesse tópico que pode te ajudar na formatação das suas publicações: [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1084/3117)

Comment: Vou dá um lida, sou usuário novo e ainda não aprendi todos os recursos do site.

Comment: Sem problemas, é só uma sugestão na verdade e pode ler outra hora se preferir, você tá ganhando bastante ponto então não precisa parar o que está fazendo ;-) Coloquei aqui apenas para você conhecer, pois conforme lá mesmo explica ninguém é obrigado a fazer daquele jeito.

Answer (score 5):

Complementando a resposta do Paulo Costa, caso você queira colocar um endereço www1, www2, www10.. no seu site, basta ir no gerenciador de DNS do seu domínio e criar um registro tipo A, conforme exemplo abaixo (o seu gerenciador pode ser um pouco diferente):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]