# Por que alguns domínios usam www2 e www3 no prefixo?

Tags: domínio, subdomínio

Por que alguns domínios usam www2 e www3 no prefixo?

Como por exemplo:

- www2.exemplo.com
- www3.exemplo.com

Notei que alguns sites como do governo usam, mas não sei o motivo ao certo.

Comment: É, do governo, né? :)

Comment: Relacionado: [Por que o endereço de alguns sites contém número após o www?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/62637/3117)

Comment: Normalmente são gambiarras, com espelhamento, aplicados quando há sobrecarga em servidores dns ou de hospedagem. Há também casos de manutenção onde precisa deixar o server principal offline.  Há meios mais apropriados para isso, porém requer uma estrutura cujo custo se torna inviável para pequenos e médio negócios ou em orçamentos apertados no caso de órgãos governamentais, etc.  Eu já usei disso em certas situações, um cliente que cresceu vertiginosamente e sem estruturas.. "Quem não tem cão, caça com gato.". Contudo, nem sempre é usado para "gambiarras". Depende de cada caso.

Comment: Grande pergunta. É aquele troço que você vê, não entende muito bem, mas deixa pra lá...

Comment: Participe da campanha **não seja um babaca** e justifique o seu voto negativo, para que eu possa melhorar a pergunta. A sua opinião é importante para a comunidade.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Os hostnames `www2, www3 e www4` são espelhos do servidor original, o objetivo principal desta técnica é reduzir a carga do servidor, realizar um balanceamento de carga ou ainda para manter o serviço online quando o servidor original precisar ser atualizado.

Como o membro @GuilhermeNascimento citou os números do hostname são sequenciais.

O que é um **hostname**: É o nome que é dado ao computador, ele serve para que possamos identificar uma maquina na rede, com mais facilidade que um numero de IP, da mesma maneira que dois corpos não podem coexistir no mesmo espaço, duas maquinas não podem possuir nomes iguais na mesma rede.

O que é um **subdomínio**: são as ramificações do domínio principal, algo muito utilizado em grandes sites. No site [suporte.seudomínio.com.br], por exemplo, [*.seudomínio.com.br] é o domínio, e "suporte" é o subdomínio, que tem a função de conduzir o usuário diretamente à seção específica do site.

Fontes:

- [Subdominio](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdom%C3%ADnio)
- [Hostname](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/WWW2)